# library referring to wrong version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, spacy

I have multiple pythons installed in my machine, 2.7, 3.5, 3.6, etc and I installed the library called spacy.

And it seems like this library keeps referring to the old version of python which is 3.5. at `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages`.

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Mar 29 2018, 03:28:50) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import spacy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/util.py", line 4, in <module>
    import ujson
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ujson'
```

Regardless of this specific library 'spacy', I'd like to know 
what is the best way to make library to point to upgraded python which is 3.6, not 3.5. Which path variable should I update?

Please help... I've been wasting too much time on this issue.

Comment: Maybe you could try to create a `virtualenv` to isolate your python environments and avoid this conflict. Maybe this can help https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Comment: The problem isn't with spacy, but with your overall Python setup. After all, Python 3.6 is clearly loading `spacy` from the 3.5 dist-packages, which it shouldn't be doing. Once it's done that, the fact that the 3.5-installed spacy is looking for other packages in 3.5 is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: To debug this, you need to know (a) do you have a `PYTHONPATH` environment variable? (b) what does `import sys; print(sys.path)` show in both 3.5 and 3.6? (c) what command do you run to start Python 3.6, and what command for 3.5? (d) how did you install 3.5 and 3.6, and spacy?

Answer (score 1):

Try to install spacy lib by running pip with required python version in module mode:

```
python3.6 -m pip install spacy
```